# How to set individual border-radius property value for mosaico blocks?

Tags: mosaico, css

I would like to set border-radius for a specific block like "border-radius 10px 10px 20px 30px;" How can I add that in the mosaico template?

I know it's possible to use -ko-border-radius: @[radius]px; but that makes all corners with the same radius. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks